# Put in elementor modal pop up box to show" Subscription Confirmed"

Tags: javascript, html, elementor

I would like assistance with code to put in elementor modal pop up box to show" Subscription Confirmed" confirmation that they have subscribed to newsletter  here is the code I'm going to use for collecting emails its from the newsletter plugin:

```
<div class="tnp tnp-subscription"><form action="https://example.com/?na=s" method="post"><input 
       name="nlang" type="hidden" value="" />
     <h1 style="text-align: center;"></h1>
     <h3>Subscribe to get 20% off your first</h3>
       <h3></h3>
      <h3>order with mysite</h3>
       <h3></h3>
        <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-email"><label></label><input class="tnp-email" name="ne" 
            required="" type="email" /></div>
         <div class="tnp-field tnp-field-button"><input class="tnp-submit" type="submit" 
              value="Subscribe" /></div>
               </form></div>
```

Thanks any help would be appreiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use alert();

```
alert("Subscription confirmed!");
```

If that doesn't suit your likings, then I recommend seeing [this](https://www.cssportal.com/blog/css-notification-boxes/#:%7E:text=%20CSS%20Notification%20Boxes%20%201%20Step%201%3A.,the%20final%20result%20by%20clicking%20the...%20More%20), and you could customize the css of the box however you want.